# Is my trigonometric proof of the Pythagorean theorem correct?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Actually, this is more of a proof for the trigonometric identity, $$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1.$$

First use right triangle, $ABC$ with angle $C$ being the right angle.

Drop an altitude from point $C$ to line $AB$ making the point $D$.

Let's name the segments: $AB = c$, $AC = b$, and $BC = a$.

Also, $AD = c_1$, $BD = c_2$, so $c_1 + c_2 = c$. Then, $b\cos A = c_1$, $a\cos B = c_2$, so $b\cos A + a\cos B = c$.

Since we know that $\angle A + \angle B = 90^\circ$, we also know that $\cos B = \sin A$.

Thus, $b\cos A + a\sin A = c$, or
$$
\frac{b}{c}\,\cos A + \frac{a}{c}\, \sin A = 1.
$$

Since $\frac{b}{c} = \cos A$ and $\frac{a}{c} = \sin A$, we have
$$
\cos^2 A + \sin^2 A = 1.
$$

Comment: Honestly this seems confused to me. Maybe pare it down by half. And use MathJax. And no ‘$*$’s are needed.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post. You can click `Edit` (or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4884093/edit)) to see how some of this formatting works and correct any errors I may have inadvertently introduced. Also, here's [a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on LaTeX/MathJax.

Comment: This appears to be related to a proof by Michel Paul described here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/TrigProofs.shtml ... which is to say, this is interesting.

Comment: related: https://meetings.ams.org/math/spring2023se/meetingapp.cgi/Person/23462

Comment: The proof as you wrote is correct.

Comment: I am not able to access the Content you gave , @Math-fun , though I can see that it says something like "the Proof is based on the law of Sines which is a fundamental result in trigonometry" : **Proving the law of Sines** will certainly make the Pythagorean theorem will come in.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. This is a real question with attested work. Is it closed because of a "circular flaw" which is well explained in the answer by Prem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie , most likely yes because it is circular logic. But looks like it has been reopened. At any rate , many questions get closed or even deleted. I have seen correct good answers by reputable people get downvoted, I have given up trying to look for a consistent logic in why bad questions might get upvoted or same duplicate questions might be upvoted where the original one was downvoted. My advice is to go with the flow :)

Comment: The law of sines, (***not*** cosines) and the definition of $\sin, \cos$ as ratios of sides of right triangles are just about the *ONLY* aspects of "trigonmetry" that do *not* rely on the basic trig identity.  As such any proof that uses *only* these is *not* circular.  It's arguably also not a "trigonometric" proof per se.  If I'd have my preference I'd prefer people not use trig terms in these proofs, but they *are* valid and not circular. I haven't combed this proof in detail but I see no reason it isn't a valid proof of P.T. Nothing circular in that.

Comment: "Is my trigonometric proof of the Pythagorean theorem correct?"  I'm going to be pedantic and say that yes, your proof is correct but that it is not *trigonometric* (in that it only relies an basic definitions but absolutely no results or concepts)

Comment: @Prem: maybe this would make it more clear what I was referring to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6j2nZKwf20

Comment: @Prem This claim is incorrect: "Proving the law of Sines will certainly make the Pythagorean theorem will come in." All one needs to do is to drop a perpendicular to the base and apply the definition of "sine" (which does not depend on Pythagoras) twice.

Comment: @JeanMarie I do not accept Prem's arguments. They are based on incorrect premises, such as that one requires Pythagoras in order to prove the law of sines. One can question, as fleablood does, whether the proof in the question is truly trigonometric, but it is not circular.

Comment: @jimjim The proof in the question is not circular.

Comment: The YouTube Presenter admits that it is not "trig" , but "trig + calculus" , because "infinite series summations" are involved. While the comments to the video there are generally Positive , @Math-fun , my thinking is in line with this comment [[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/chTho.png ]] Maybe if somebody makes a question at MSE about that method , we might analyze in more Detail there !

Comment: (1) "incorrect premises, such as that one requires Pythagoras in order to prove the law of sines" : I might have (or should have) said something like "Euclidean Postulates [ including Parallel Postulate ] are necessary to show Similarity Property on which sine law depends" , @DavidK , I will try to reword. (2) "One can question whether Proof is trigonometric, but it is not Circular" : I agree with that , though the Proof is incomplete & only when the Missing Parts are added , we can claim Circularity or not. What Definitions/assumptions/theorems are needed (& not needed) is not clearly given.

Comment: A useful thing one might do in answering a question like this would be to show how a more experienced person might refer to the necessary prior definitions and facts.

Answer (score 4):

The identity $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ is essentially the Pythagorean Theorem in the form of trigonometry.

In your proof you use the fact that triangles with congruent angles are similar.
This is an essential fact that enables us to define the sine and cosine functions for acute angles using the three sides of a right triangle,
from which you get the formulas $\frac bc = \cos A$ and so forth.

It is not necessary to use the Pythagorean Theorem to prove that
triangles with congruent angles are similar.
Then, as detailed in
[On the Possibility of Trigonometric Proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2009volume9/FG200925.pdf) by Jason Zimba,
the sine and cosine functions (at least, the versions of those functions that you used) are well-defined.

There is a related discussion at [Cut-the-Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/TrigProof.shtml).

---

While I found the proof adequate and non-circular, I had to rely on knowledge that the sine and cosine functions can be well defined using the high-school "triangle" definition without depending on the Pythagorean Theorem.
This is an essential fact for any claim that this is a valid non-circular proof. Since people generally don't consider proving the Pythagorean Theorem by trigonometry, it would seem advisable to be a bit more explicit about your assumptions of prior results and definitions.

It's probably worth mentioning at the start if the corresponding angles of  two triangles are equal, corresponding sides of those triangles are proportional, and that this fact can be proved from Euclidean axioms without first proving the Pythagorean Theorem.

Due to the preceding fact, we can define the sine and cosine of positive acute angles as follows: if a right triangle $PQR$ with right angle at $Q$ has angle $\alpha$ at $P$, then $\sin(\alpha) = QR/PR$ and $\cos(\alpha) = PQ/PR$.

This defines enough "trigonometry" for you to complete your proof.

---

An additional comment: on further consideration, I think it can be helpful to present this proof as a proof of the identity
$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$
(as you did in the question itself)
rather than as a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem (as the question title presents it).
That way, the fact that you use only very elementary facts of trigonometry might be excused by the fact that almost anything more advanced would require proving this identity (or something equally advanced) first.

Answer (score 2):

**It is neither right nor wrong , though it is useful to improve basic intuition.**

Euclidean Geometry ( with the list of Axioms & Postulates including the Parallel Postulate ) gives the Pythagorean theorem.

Euclidean Geometry [ with Similarity Property & Pythagorean theorem ] gives rise to trigonometry.
**[[ Consider $a^2+b^2=c^2$ : Divide by $c^2$ : $(a/c)^2+(b/c)^2=(c/c)^2$ : Write in trigonometric form : $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ ]]**

Hence it is circular logic to say trigonometry can give Pythagorean theorem.

What your thinking has given is the important intuitive concept that trigonometry & Pythagorean theorem are consistent ( or at least not inconsistent ) limiting to this calculation.

**Euclidean Geometry ( with Pythagorean theorem & Etc ) & trigonometry ( with the given Identity & other Concepts ) are two sides of the same coin !**

---

### ADDENDUM :

Answer above is self-contained & this Section can be skipped in toto. It is mostly going to elaborate what is given above , while responding to certain concerns raised , including those not relevant to OP Post.
Unfortunately , it might turn out very long , which is the unavoidable consequence of the abstract nature of the Discussion.

It has become too long , sounding like some Opinion Piece ! Posting this , I have great hesitation , though I have to keep my promise of responding to the comments.

---

(1) Elisha Scott Loomis has reviewed centuries of Proof Suggestions & concluded that the trigonometry way is circular , which is the conclusion of the thoughts of **hundreds of geometers** over the ages , while Jason Zimba is relatively new & not well reviewed. It might be true or there might be loopholes not yet reveled by thorough assessments by **hundreds of geometers** : Until then , I will withhold judgement on that. When necessary , I will change my stand. I will try to high-light why I am currently not changing my stand.

(2) Let us say we have arbitrary PT Proof like this : **"Axioms , Postulates , Consequence1 , Lemma1 , Lemma2 , Consequence2 , therefore $a^2=c^2/2-x$ , $b^2=c^2/2+x$ , adding these we get PyTheo"**
Then dividing thought-out by $c^2$ , we get TrigID.
OK , now we want to ignore or deliberate avoid PyTheo , hence we can easily avoid naming it or avoid isolating that fact , to get TrigID like this , using the Exact Same Machinery : **"Axioms , Postulates , Consequence1 , Lemma1 , Lemma2 , Consequence2 , therefore $a^2=c^2/2-x$ , $b^2=c^2/2+x$ , now we can divide though-out by $c^2$ to get $\sin^2 \theta = 1/2 - x/c^2$ , $\cos^2 \theta = 1/2 + x/c^2$ , adding these we get TrigID"**

Is that really Trig Way or PyTheo in Disguise ( using the term given by user "Intelligenti pauca" ) or Is it PyTheo hiding in plain sight which we want to not see ?

Explaining that Point in other words , say we are given $x+2y=3$ , $4x-5y=6$ & we want to get $x/y$. We can solve the Simultaneous Equations to first get $x$ , then $y$ , then get the ratio. Is it essentially same when we get $y$ first , then $x$ , then the ratio ?
I think it is essentially same. Like-wise here.

(3) Is the given Proof Correct ? Yes , it is Correct. Is it avoiding PT ? No , PT is still there , though somewhat hidden.
The outstanding issues which are not clarified in that Proof :
How can we say all right angle triangles with same angles have same ratios ? ( It is using Similarity of triangles with same angles )
When we say $ \sin A= \cos B$ , we assume $A+B=90^\circ$ : How can we say angles add up to $90^\circ$ ? It is true only in Euclidean geometry that triangles add up to $180^\circ$. We are implicitly using Parallel Postulate ( & more! ) here.
Not many users are aware of Non-Euclidean geometry , who might think it is nonsensical to question whether triangle adds up to $=180^\circ$ which is generally considered obvious. Truth is : there are cases where it is $<180^\circ$ & there are cases where it is $>180^\circ$.

To reduce the size of this Discussion , I will avoid elaborating on the Uniqueness of Point $D$ no matter how or where we have the given triangle [ Euclid does consider such things in various other Cases ]

(4) A comment by user David K says "There are various sequences in which the pieces can be assembled" with which I agree. More-over "Similarity of triangles with equal angles can be proved without having first proved the Pythagorean Theorem and therefore is not necessarily dependent on the Pythagorean Theorem" is also true. But that should be put in the Post , to make it self-contained , showing what was used & what was not used. Only then that we can claim that it is not redundant or not circular or just renaming.

When we assemble a sequence of arguments to generate 4 or 5 "theorems" at once , including PyTheo & TrigID , then we can not say these are derived independently : the line of argument already includes the machinery for PyTheo , we just wrote the outcomes in some order.

(5) A comment by user ultralegend5385 says "no one cares so much about Euclidean geometry or its postulates when doing analysis" , which is true to a certain extent. There are various Geometry Proof Concepts for matching Derivatives with tangent lines & for mean value theorems & for Evaluating Derivative of $\sin(x)$ geometrically/trigonometrically & even for getting the arc length of curves using $(dx)^2+(dy)^2=(ds)^2$ ( I think , there is no escape of this )

The Comment continues with "triangle ratio follows immediately as a theorem, and the other results like the derivative of $\sin(x)$ , or properties like $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ follow immediately (**without using any Euclidean geometry**)" , which is not true.
Euclidean geometry has already been used at the lower levels & we ignore it at higher levels.
If not , it will wrongly imply that calculus + analysis is enough to derive Euclidean geometry , analysis supports Euclidean geometry only , thus Parallel Postulate is true , other (Non-Euclidean) geometries are not consistent with calculus + analysis + real numbers !

When we think about analytic ways to Define trig functions , say $\sin_a$ & $\cos_a$ , we have to use geometry as the hidden base. Without using geometric ways like $\sin_g$ & $\cos_g$ , we might think of what Properties we want the analytic functions to have.
Property 1 : $\sin_a^2 x + \cos_a^2 x = 1$
This is satisfied by $\sin_a x = \sqrt x$ , $\cos_a x = \sqrt {1-x}$ , which is not want we want.
Property 2 : Derivatives alternate between $\sin$ & $cos$ , while $y^{[4]}=y$ , that is , 4th Derivative gives back the function.
This is satisfied by $\sin_a x = e^{-x}$ , $\cos_a x = -e^{-x}$ , which is not want we want.
Eventually , we will have to use the original geometry or trigonometry like this :
Property 3 : We want $\sin_a \equiv \sin_g$ & $\cos_a \equiv \cos_g$ , in the Domain $(0,\pi)$
What-ever functions we now consider will have to match. Proof will necessarily involve geometry to show the Equivalence which will be consistent over-all. There is no escaping that. It might be the the Equivalence is hidden in the abstraction at the lower level & not easily visible at the high level.

(6) Comment by user fleablood says "The OPs prove is purely euclidean pre-Pyth. Th. but post similar triangles" , with which I agree.
Comment continues with "It is, in essence, a purely euc geo proof of Pyth. th. ..." , very true , though we have to fill-in the Missing Parts to check whether the Trig Part is just renaming or redundant or circular , to respond to OP Question title.

Comment concludes with "Prefer if such a proof eschewed mentioning trig names as it misleads" , which is what I have excruciatingly typed out here.

---

I better stop typing now. It is looking like some abstruse Philosophy text , which may well be what this is !

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/TrigProof.shtml

Comment: Well , that is using the Subtraction formulas which are unproven there , @DavidK , I am certain that the Subtraction formulas were derived using Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @Prem: Trigonometric functions and hence their identities, are more often and most commonly defined using some way other than ratio of sides of triangles, and then the fact that the triangle ratios are trigonometric functions is proved. So, the Pythagoras theorem can very well be proved using trigonometric functions.

Comment: (1) Trigonometry is based on the fact that all right angle triangles with same angles are "similar" & have the same ratios. (2) We use Euclidean geometry & Pythagorean theorem to get that fact , @ultralegend5385 , otherwise there is no Trigonometry. (3) When we use other ways to introduce trigonometric functions , even then we will have to use Euclidean geometry to eventually show the equivalence with right angle triangles. (4) Note to random unknown Down-voter : Down-voting based on ignorance is Counter Productive to learning & knowledge.

Comment: @Prem Read this: https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2009volume9/FG200925.pdf After all, this is nothing but the beatiful proof by Euclid (El. VI-31), disguised by introducing trig functions.

Comment: Geometry is an edifice that is built one stone at a time, not a monolith that is delivered all at once. There are various sequences in which the pieces can be assembled. Similarity of triangles with equal angles can be proved without having first proved the Pythagorean Theorem and therefore is not necessarily dependent on the Pythagorean Theorem. The definitions of the basic trig functions depend on similar triangles but again do not depend on the Pythagorean Theorem. It is a **theorem** of trigonometry, not a definition, that $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$.

Comment: I have no idea who cast the downvote or what their knowledge of geometry and trigonometry is, but there is no good reason to say the downvote was based on ignorance. One should always be ready to learn something new. The link I posted in the first comment is from an expert who was as sure as you are that there is no non-circular trig proof of the Pythagorean Theorem, but rather than call people ignorant he studied the proof and changed his mind.

Comment: @Prem: No one cares so much about Euclidean geometry or its postulates when doing analysis (which is where trigonometric functions are really defined, so are most of the functions we study, as well). The standard way (which is far more useful) is to define them as either real and imaginary parts of $e^{ix}$, or the power series, or solutions to a system of differential equations. The triangle ratio follows immediately as a theorem, and the other results like the derivative of $\sin(x)$, or properties like $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ follow immediately (**without** using any Euclidean geometry).

Comment: " (2) We use Euclidean geometry & Pythagorean theorem to get that fact " We use euc geo, not pythagorean th. to get the fact right triangles are similar. The OPs prove *is* purely euclidean pre-Pyth. Th. but post similar triangles.  It is only "trigometric" in that it is using $\sin, \cos$ to refer to the legs of a rght triangle with unit hypothesis. It is, in essence, a purely euc geo proof of Pyth. th. and there is nothing magically off limits or circular in that. (Admittely I'd prefer if such a proof eschewed mentioning trig names as it misleads)

Comment: I see that there are quite a few comments to which I would like to respond. There might be yet more users & yet more comments shortly. Hence I will delay my response by around a few hours which will enable me to cover all comments in one shot.